# How to pass an array to a new page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

hi everyone i need to pass an array value to a new html page.
i tried but the array value is always resetting

here is my code

```
var cart=[];
var jumlah=0;
var total=0;


function add(index)
{
if(index==1)
{
    jumlah=prompt("masukan jumlah");
    if(jumlah==0||jumlah<0||jumlah==null)
    {
        alert("harap masukkan jumlah, dengan format yang benar");
    }
    else
    {
    total=jumlah*500000;
    cart.push('Razer Destructor Battlefield @ IDR 500.000|| Jumlah '+jumlah+' || total '+total);
    for(var i=0;i<cart.length;i++)
    {
        alert("barang telah di tambahkan ke keranjang");
    }
    }
}
else if(index==2)
{
    jumlah=prompt("masukan jumlah");
    if(jumlah==0||jumlah<0||jumlah==null)
    {
        alert("harap masukkan jumlah dengan format yang benar");
    }
    else{
    total=jumlah*2020000;
    cart.push('Razer blackwidow ultimate mechanical keyboard for gaming @ IDR 2,020,000|| Jumlah '+jumlah+' || total '+total);
    alert("barang telah di tambahkan ke keranjang");
    }
}}
```

i need to pass that cart[] array from product.html to a a new page called cart.html

can u guys help me? sorry im a beginner and sorry for bad english. thanks for ur help!!

Comment: Store your `cart` array using localStorage/sessionStorage and then access it on the next page. [Reference](http://diveintohtml5.info/storage.html)

Comment: its not possible to transfer content between HTML pages instead use **Web Storage** http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/

Comment: do it in server side  instead of using javascript

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should have a look to [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Storage)

```
window.localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart)); // Saving
var cart = JSON.parse(window.localStorage.getItem("cart")); // Retrieving
```

Comment: thank neovov!!but am i need a different javascript on my cart.html page?

Comment: No, just use `localStorage.setItem` to save your cart in the browser, and `localStorage.getItem` to retrieve your data.

Answer (score 1):

If you're supporting recent browsers, to save do:

```
localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
```

To retrieve it from other html page in the same domain:

```
var cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
```

If you have to support old browsers, apply the same logic but saving in cookies.

Cheers

Comment: thank Edgar!!but am i need a different javascript on my cart.html page?

Comment: Yes, you can, but first you have to remove the line `var cart = [];`